# How to refer to instance properties at runtime in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, runtime, properties, instance

There is a trick Flash Actionscript developers can do to refer to instance properties at runtime.  I was wondering if anything similar existed in Objective-C

In actionscript we can do:

```
var thisObject;
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   thisObject = this["myInstanceProperty"+i];
   thisObject.doSomething();
}
```

I thought there would be a method similar to this in Objective-C, but I can't find anything mentioned anywhere.  I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  NSString *buttonName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_%i", i];
  id *thisButton = [self instancePropertyWithStringName:buttonName];
  thisButton.label = @"button %i";
}
```

Can you see what I'm getting at?  I have a xib linking views to IBOutlets, and I'd like to refer to those IBOutlets from within a for loop, so I can add properties to them dynamically at runtime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following if the `self` object conforms to `NSKeyValueCoding` -- which it does by default for its instance variables and properties.

```
NSButton *button = [self valueForKey:buttonName];
```

Comment: Also if buttonName isn't a property. Also, the cast to NSButton is not needed. Also, to set the value [self setValue:foo forKey:buttonName]

Comment: @fakeAccount22 You're right and I edited my post. I posted this from school with a minute left before the bell, so I didn't have time to check the details ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Key-Value Coding Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).